# How to handle regular expression in ubuntu batch script that deal with IPv6

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-14.04, ipv6

I used radvd to generate 64-bit prefix in a format 3002:0200:00bc:098a::/64, but it appears in the eth0 of a client device in the form of 3002:200:bc:98a::/64. Now i have script that extracts this address and saves to file for eg "temp"as 3002:200:bc:98a . I need to change it now to the form 3002:0200:00bc:098a  Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
3002:200:bc:98a
20:1:ad:8b

$ perl -lpe 's/[^:]+/sprintf "%04s", $&/ge' ip.txt
3002:0200:00bc:098a
0020:0001:00ad:008b
```

- `[^:]+` field to transform
- `ge` where `g` is for replacing all matches and `e` is to allow Perl code in replacement section
- `sprintf "%04s", $&` format the matched string as required